How do you capture the startup error when starting a .NET 8 console app from a .NET 4.8 application when .NET 8.0 is not installed?
I am trying to launch a .NET 8 console application from a .NET 4.8 application and capture the stdout to use that output in the .NET 4.8 application. This all works.
However, if .NET 8.0 is not installed when I launch the console application from a cmd prompt I get the following:

App: d:\temp\DotNet8ConsoleApp.exe
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '8.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\
The following frameworks were found:
2.1.30 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
3.1.10 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
3.1.32 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
5.0.4 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
5.0.9 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
5.0.17 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
6.0.8 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
6.0.26 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
6.0.31 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
7.0.20 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=8.0.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64

However, this text does not show up in stdout or stderror when calling the process nor does it throw an exception, it simply closes.
Following is a sample .NET 4.8 console application:
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Text;

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            var process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"d:\temp\DotNet8ConsoleApp.exe";
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; // Required for redirection
            process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => sb.Append(e.Data);
            process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) => sb.Append(e.Data);
            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

The output of the above program outputs a blank line.
Any ideas?

I think process.Start() returns a bool.  If it's false, it didn't start.  It can also throw some errors, so try/catch.  You might just build the .NET8 self-contained to avoid the error though.  (and/or create a single .NET8 app instead of 2 separate apps)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/how-to-detect-installed-versions?pivots=os-windows
